# List of files different between files committed to branch and master

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to set up some automated linting on Gitlab.

We have a repository with a number of Python scripts and Jupyter notebooks.

On a regular basis we will clone a new branch from `master`, make changes, commit new or modified (or both) scripts to the new remote branch then create a Merge Request on Gitlab to merge the files into `master`.

I'm trying to lint **only** these changed files on commit, and I don't want the Merge Request to be merged until the linting pipeline has succeeded (this is a Gitlab feature which I have enabled on the repository).

In order to do this, I need to know which files have changed between the commit and, preferably, the `master` branch.

To begin with, I was using this command: `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SH`

This worked in isolation of the `master` branch, e.g. it simply listed all files changed as part of the commit. On an individual commit, this works brilliantly.

However, we ran into the following problem:

- 3 files committed -> All fail lint -> Pipeline fails, MR blocked
- 2 files fixed and committed -> Both pass lint -> Pipeline succeeds
- MR is now possible because the latest pipeline has succeeded, despite 1 file still being in a "lint-failed" state

So now the approach that I'm taking is to try and compare the commits - and the files being merged as part of the Merge Request (this is possible in Gitlab, `on: merge`) - to the `master` branch.

I've tried using `git diff master --name-status` but this returns all files in the repository.

I've tried using `git diff $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME..master --name-status` which works perfectly locally, but during the Gitlab pipeline I get the error `fatal: ambiguous argument 'mybranch..master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`.

Have I done something wrong with the syntax on this call, or is there a better way I can approach this? I'm at the stage where I've contemplated trying to manually retrieve file sizes, then `git checkout` to a different branch and retrieve the file sizes of that branch for comparison purposes... but that's quite a lot of work, and similarly difficult to do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks to me like your git diff command itself is right, the question is whether `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` is defined correctly while the hook is being executed. Does `mybranch` exist on Gitlab when the command is run? Have you tried using `$CI_COMMIT_SHA` instead? That should also point to the commit you want to compare, I think. Does the merge hook get run before or after the merge? If it gets run after, you'll want to get the two parents of the commit, or possibly `git diff $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA`. If you're able to generate logs, adding `env >&2` might help you find the variable you need to use.

Comment: `mybranch` definitely exists when the pipeline runs. If I use the commit hash, won't I encounter the exact same problem as I did in the bullet points listed on my post? I'll plug `env >&2` in now and see what happens.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand why `git diff master --name-status` returns all files. That would suggest that HEAD is sitting on an empty status of the repo. No, I don't think using `$CI_COMMIT_HASH` would have the same behaviour. Maybe logging `git status >&2` would help too, to see where HEAD is? And even `git show >&2`, to see what it contains.

Comment: So `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=mybranch` as expected. `status` shows `HEAD detached at 980bf9b` || `nothing to commit, working tree clean`. `show` gives information about the changes such as `--- a/linting/run-lints.sh` || `+++ b/linting/run-lints.sh`.

Comment: And I assume nothing yet works as you want... Maybe `git branch -a -v >&2` would tell you what branches exist and where they are at? I feel like I'm just leading you on a goose chase... Hopefully something will click and make sense in all those logs...

Comment: Interestingly, when I change the `git diff` syntax to `git diff mybranch master`, the response is `fatal: ambiguous argument 'mybranch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`. I wondered if perhaps the version of `git` we're using had a different syntax or something, but clearly syntax isn't the issue - the pipeline, at that specific time, thinks that either the `mybranch` branch doesn't exist or is *ambiguous* in other ways... does that tickle any knowledge cavities in your head? :)

Comment: Then all I could think is look at what `git branch -a -v >&2` outputs. Is `mybranch` listed? No, I don't think the syntax would be different, that is absolutely basic `git diff` syntax since forever.

Comment: And seriously, `env >&2` didn't show a single variable with the SHA1 hash of the head of `mybranch` before the merge? That would be so simple if it did... Or `git show HEAD >&2` should show you, among other things, the SHA1's of the two parents of the merge commit, in a line like `merge: 23dca563 123fdec1`. You could parse that to extract the SHA1's of the two commits you want to compare. That was my hope anyway.

Comment: I don't use Gitlab so this is [a shot in the dark](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/a-shot-in-the-dark), but: it sounds like the *other* Git repository, the one Gitlab is using, does not have a branch named `mybranch`. It's probably identifying commits by their hash IDs, which would be the smart way to do it: hash IDs don't change, branch names do, so use the ones that really mean something (hash IDs). If so, you should do the same.